# AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF' no solutions found worked

Tags: python-3.x, django, azure, azure-web-app-service

I know this is a known issue, but no solutions on other threads have helped me. No matter what I do, I get this error in Azure Stream logs, everything works fine when I run the project locally.

my wsgi.py file:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mojspecjalista.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My project url file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('App.api.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

manage.py:

```
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mojspecjalista.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and lastly my settings:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mojspecjalista.urls'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your `wsgi.py` file correctly sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'mojspecjalista.settings', and ensure your project structure is consistent. Double-check that all necessary files and configurations are deployed and restart the server if needed. Make sure your packages are up to date.

ROOT_URLCONF is correctly referred to according to your project structure.

I tried your code with minor changes, and I successfully deployed the Python Django app to Azure App Service.

**manage .py**

```py
import os
import sys

def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mydjango.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my **mydjango/urls.py**:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('myapp.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
if  settings.DEBUG:

urlpatterns  +=  static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the content of my **settings .py** file:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'secretekey'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS =  ['yourazurewebappname.azurewebsites.net', 'yourdomain.azurewebsites.net', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mydjango.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mydjango.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**myapp/views.py**

```py
from  django.http  import  HttpResponse

def  my_view(request):

return  HttpResponse("Hello, Django!")
```

**myapp/urls.py**

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import my_view  # Import your view function
urlpatterns = [
    path('', my_view, name='my-view'),
    # Add other URL patterns for your app as needed
]
```

**myapp/models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    field2 = models.IntegerField()
```

**Local** **Output** :
[image]

[image]

[image]

I deployed the code to the Azure App Service using the VS Code Azure Extension.

[image]

The deployment to Azure App Service was successful.

[image]

**Azure Output** :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello mate, I've decided to go firstly with updating to Python 12 and then to Django 5, which was problematic by a lot, after few hours yesterdays I wanted to continue, but my free credits at Azure are spend, so I'm unable to continue to work on Azure. Thanks a lot for such detailed answer, but I need to move to another portal, who'd guess it's so expensive...